# No field match identifier (SBL-DAT-00416)

Tags: siebel

Currently im doing Siebel Open UI. I got 3 drop down choices which are :

1. Account No
2. Transaction Date
3. Fund Code

All field above are calculated field. I create different picklist for every calculated field above. Account No and Transaction Date are from BC (A) but Fund Code is from BC (B). In order to put Fund Code in same Applet with another 2 field above, i had created calculated field in BC (A) and put Fund Code field there. But it keep come out with this error.

Kindly assist me on this issue.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pull a field from defined in BC "B" into an applet which is based on BC "A" ? This cannot d be done. OpenUI runs on the UI layer, but the rules of the second business layer still hold true. Every applet has a Business Component behind it and you can only map the fields of that underlying BC onto that applet.

You will have to define all three calculated fields on the same BC "A" inorder to map them to the applet.